# laravel passport custom value user_id in table oauth_access_tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have master table user with name `employee`, So I wan't use that table not default table from laravel auth `users`. How to modify laravel passport so that I can use column from `employee` table?

this my login code

```
public function login(){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('nApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/auth.php` you have providers and providers have drivers...
So the drivers make it to the model you want to use...
If you have some authentication process that use User model, then you can use helper function : `auth('YOUR GUARD NAME')->user()`.
Your guard name is in `config/auth.php` too.